# Suggestion for write frequently, read rarely database

Tags: mysql, mongodb, redis, database, nosql

I have an application server which writes frequently to a database and reads it in the near future, but then very rarely that data entry is read.

What is some good databases optimised for this kind of access? I am currently using MongoDB but I think that probably isnt the best choice in this case.

I am open to relational DBs (i.e. MySQL), MongoDB, Redis, etc.

P.S. Seems it's easy to answer this question for read frequently DB access, but hard to find information on this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very generic question, We need to know more details

- Size of Database
- Data growth, How much 10GB per day / 200GB per month ?
- Is it a OLTP Application or OLAP Application ?
- What is maximum number of concurrent transactions / users ?

Apart from it, Since you have mentioned data is rarely read beyond a certain point

- You can always look at options for Archival (Cleaning up based on duration - Monthly basis / Yearly basis)
- Parititioning is also another option, for faster retrieval

Again the option for going for SQL or NOSQL is based on

- Consistency
- If you have a fixed schema I would suggest you to go for Relational DB
- Concurrency aspects, Based on need you need to decided SQL or NOSQL (example - online banking i would suggest RDBMS, For product reviews/comments storing for a site, I am ok for NOSQL as this does not need any concurrency handling)

You need to provide more details on your database need in terms of functionality, data volumes, data usage and growth aspects

Hope it helps...

Comment: It's an OLTP based App. Size of the database is small now, but may grow quickly. There is no binary data stored - just text (no numbers either, maybe timestamps though).

I cant really predict data growth yet, but I am anticipating having to archive data off regularly to keep inserts and young data access quick.

Can have many concurrent transactions, but the data is not required to be relational. Data doesnt reference each other yet, and I cant think of how concurrent access could affect it (since each user is pretty much accessing only their own keys).

Comment: Continuing (max text length), I would like the schema to be very flexible whilst I'm still in heavy development as it will likely need to change often until I get it settled.

P.S. VERY HELPFUL RESPONSE! :-D

Comment: I'm not sure how much flexible schema. Are you referring unstructured data ?. From your replies both SQL and NOSQL would achieve your purpose. Based on developer skill/comfort in terms of SQL/NOSQL you have to take that call.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention MySQL, you might want to look at the [ARCHIVE storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/archive-storage-engine.html).